Finite I-cell complex and relative finite I-cell complex
For a cofibrantly generated model category $\mathcal{C}$ (which is precisely generated by $\mathscr{I}$ and $\mathscr{J}$), and a finite $\mathscr{I}$-cell complex $X$ in $\mathcal{C}$, is there always a factorization of the map $(\mathsf{id}_X, \mathsf{id}_X) \colon X\amalg X \to X$, such that
$$X\amalg X \xrightarrow{(i_0,i_1)} X' \xrightarrow{r} X$$
where $(i_0,i_1)$ is a relative finite $\mathscr{I}$-cell complex and $r$ is a weak equivalence?
I know that there is alway a factorization $f=\alpha(f)\circ \beta(f)$ for any map $f$ in $\mathcal{C}$, such that the $\alpha(f)$ is a relative $\mathscr{I}$-cell complex and $\beta(f)$ a weak equivalence, in general. However, I was wondering if we could construct a special factorization to make the first map 'finite' in this special case?
(Note that a (relative) finite $ \mathscr{I} $‑cell complex means that both the factorization and the coproduct of morphisms in $ \mathscr{I} $ are finite.)
